# Assets in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like add CSS to one Action/View in my Project. In Symfony i can use for this config/view.yml in specific folder. This add CSS to section HEAD.
In Symfony i use:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/acme_foo/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

but this add CSS in current place, not in section HEAD. How is the best method in Symfony2 to add CSS and JS for one action/view in section HEAD of HTML?

Comment: What does your prjector structur look like?

Comment: Typical... Same as in documentation

Comment: I basically mean what twig-files you have. Because you could just extend a template(http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) and define the stlysheet and javaScript then in a block-tag.

Comment: thanks, please add new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it as a code-block by [extending the template](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html).